# what is the best free ftp component for delphi

Tags: delphi, ftp, delphi-6

I'm using delphi6, and our company don't want to upgrade it,
and I found Tidftp lack the MLSD command,
So what is the free ftp component you are using now?

ps : I searched for one on Google, but I don't know which is stable and standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php), but I hear good things and it looks good.  The [SVN on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synalist) has much newer code.

> - Support for FTP protocol (support many
>     firewalls including custom ones,
>     upload and dowload resuming, transfer
>     between two FTP servers). Implemented
>     directory list parsing too. SSL/TLS
>     support.
> - Support for TFTP protocol (client and
>     server).

Beyond that I have had good luck with [Indy's TidFTP](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/index.EN.aspx), although I have used Indy 9 more than 10.

BTW, I don't know about the MLSD command specifically, but it seems like there was a way to send custom commands to the server with Indy.  I know I actually used it to implement a more detailed directory listing, so that may have been the MLSD then . . ..

Comment: I have used Synapse with great success specifically in writing FTP clients.  The nice thing about Synapse is that it is simple to add new commands (if necessary) as the code is very easy to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Done!

download the newest [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.EN.aspx) component, and TidFtp is good to use!

Answer (score 1):

You can also check ICS TFtpCli

http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html